# contadores y sumadores en struct

Tags: c, codeblocks

donde debo inicializar los contadores y sumadores de un struct? probe inicializando despues del for que esta antes del switch y me tiro basura, si lo pongo antes de las otras iteraciones me larga 0, estoy medio perdido porque es la primera vez q utilizo struct, al igual que el sumador que tampoco funciona, simplifique el codigo para que se viera solo el primer caso

```
struct alumno{
            int edad ;
            char sexo;
            int cantf;
            int cantm;
            int totf;
            int totm;
            }e1[];
        
        int main()
        {
            int curso,i,ca,edadprom1=0,f1,fd1,n;
        
            struct alumno * e1 = (struct alumno*)malloc(n * sizeof(struct alumno));
        
         
            printf("ingrese el numero del curso al que se quiere ingresar: (1 al 6): ");
            scanf("%d",&curso);
            printf("ingrese la cantidad de alumnos por curso: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            while(curso!=0){
        
                    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    e1[i].totf=0;
                    switch (curso){
                    case 1:
        
                        printf("ingrese la edad del alumno %d del curso %d: ",i,curso);
                           scanf("%d",&e1[i].edad);
                           edadprom1=edadprom1+e1[i].edad;
                           e1[i].totf=e1[i].totf++;
                           printf("ingrese el sexo del alumno: ");
                           scanf("%s",&e1[i].sexo);
                      if (e1[i]=='f'){
                        e1[i].f1=e1[i].f1+1;
                       }
                           break;
             }
            }
                       printf("ingrese el numero del curso al que se quiere ingresar: (1 al 6) o 0 para finalizar:");
                       scanf("%d",&curso);
            }
            printf("f1= %d",e1[i].totf);
            free(e1);
            
            return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Te prometo que lei varias veces la pregunta y no he logrado
entenderla. No se si puedes clarificar en a que te refieres?
O si puedes compartir el problema que estas tratando de
resolver? **PD:** Porque colocas `char sexo[1]`? Si solo es
uno no seria mejor colocar: `char sexo`?

Comment: ahi realice la modificacion de mi pregunta

Comment: Y ¿cual es la pregunta entonces?

Comment: me olvide de agregar en la explicacion xd, donde debo inicializar los contadores y sumadores de el struct? porque cuando itero me tira basura, realice el primero y inicializando el contador e1[i}.totf antes del for que esta antes del switch pero no me resulto

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon ahí "tus preguntas" o "tus dudas". Si alguien tiene que leerse los comentarios para poder responder, tus preguntas van a perder mucho interés

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás mezclando conceptos.

Para empezar, un curso tiene `N` alumnos, luego la estructura que tu profesor espera se parece más a ésta:

```
struct alumno
{
    int edad;
    char sexo;
};
```

Tu ahora estás declarando cada curso en una variable independiente:

```
struct alumno e1[N], e2[N], e3[N], ...
```

Esto tiene el problema de que, como no estás creando funciones, tienes que duplicar 6 veces el mismo código. Lo dicho, o usas funciones o creas un array de cursos:

```
#define NUM_ALUMNOS 5
#define NUM_CURSOS 6
struct alumno cursos[NUM_CURSOS][NUM_ALUMNOS];
```

Esto te permite iterar sobre los cursos:

```
for(int i=0; i<NUM_CURSOS; i++)
{
    printf("Curso %d\n", i+1);
    printf("Datos de los alumnos:\n");
    
    for( int i=0; i<NUM_ALUMNOS; i++)
    {
        printf("ingrese la edad del alumno %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&cursos[i][j].edad);
        printf("ingrese el sexo del alumno: ");
        scanf("%c",&cursos[i][j].sexo); // <--- %c para caracteres sueltos
    }
}
```

> donde debo inicializar los contadores y sumadores de el struct? porque cuando itero me tira basura

Esas variables debes calcularlas, obviamente:

```
for(int i=0; i<NUM_CURSOS; i++)
{
    float edad_promedio = 0;
    float edad_propedio_mujeres=0;
    int cantidad_mujeres = 0;
    int cantidad_hombres = 0;

    for( int i=0; i<NUM_ALUMNOS; i++)
    {
        edad_promedio += curso[i][j].edad;
       
        if (curso[i][j].sexo == 'M')
        {
            cantidad_mujeres++;
            edad_promedio_mujeres += curso[i][j].edad;
        }
    }

    edad_promedio /= NUM_ALUMNOS;
    edad_promedio_mujeres /= cantidad_mujeres;

    printf("Resultados del curso %d\n", i+1);
    printf("Edad promedio: %f\n", edad_promedio);
    printf("Edad promedio mujeres: %f\n", edad_promedio_mujeres);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias! una ultima consulta, en cursos[i][j] debo inicializar j en 0 justo antes del for? cuando uso el %c  al en caracter no me lo toma cuando lo ejecuto directamente pasa al alumno 2,

Comment: eso es porque debes limpiar el buffer antes de leer con `%c`. una llamada a `getch()` antes del `scanf("%c"`, o un espacio antes del % `scanf(" %c"` y listo

Comment: realice el algoritmo como usted me dijo, y compilo y todo pero los sumadores y contadores no almacenan, esta exactamente igual

Comment: @MaxiDominguez si no almacenan entonces no es exactamente igual. Mi intención no es hacerte la deberes sino ayudarte a entender esta parte. El ejercicio requiere esfuerzo por tu parte

Comment: @MaxiDominguez por favor, nota que la respuesta no te resuelve todo el ejercicio. Hay variables que no se tocan